# Finding the Maximum Inversion Sum of an Array

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, time-complexity, kadanes-algorithm

You are given a 0-indexed array `vect` of `n` integers. You need to perform the following 2 operations exactly once-

- Choose an index `i` {0, 1, 2, ..., n-1} and multiply the entire **prefix segment {0..i}** by -1.
- Choose an index `j` {0, 1, 2, ..., n-1} and multiply the entire **suffix segment {j...n-1}** by -1.

Choosing `i` and `j`, we need to maximize the entire sum of all elements of the array.

Note: 
It is possible for the prefix and suffix segments to overlap, i.e. when *`i = j`* or *`i > j`*. As expected, when a sub-segment undergoes both operations, it's value remains unchanged.

**Approach**:

- Make the array 1-based and calculate the prefix `pref` and suffix `suff` sums.
- While calculating the maximum sum at any index `i` and `j` where *`i < j`*, we have 
  `sum = (-1)*pref[i] + Z + (-1)*suff[j]` 
  Z can be calculated as `pref[j-1] - pref[(i+1)-1]`. `Z = {}` when `j - i = 1`.
- We can only have `j > i` as overlapping sub-segments would remain the same and have no effect on the final answer.
- Iterate for different values of `i` and `j`.

Time Complexity - **`O(n^2)`**

**Observations**

- If none of the elements in `pref` is negative, we can only negate `pref[1]` to reduce the maximum sum as little as possible. Similarly, for `suff` we can do `suff[n]`.
- If atleast one of the elements in both `pref` and `suff` is negative, lets say `pref[i] < 0` and `suff[j] < 0`, our maximum answer will always involve negating `pref[i]` or `suff[j]` or both if `i < j`.

We can do slight optimizations using the above observations, but it would not change the Time Complexity (a case where all elements in `vect` are negative, leading to `pref` and `suff` have all negative elements).

**Code** (in C++)

```
using ll = long long;

ll getMaxInvSum(vector<int> vect) {
    int n = vect.size();
    
    vector<ll> pref(n+2), suff(n+2); // add dummy element at the front and back of vect
    
    pref[0] = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) pref[i+1] = pref[i] + vect[i];
    pref[n+1] = pref[n]; 
    
    suff[n+1] = 0;
    for(int j=n-1; j>=0; j--) suff[j+1] = suff[j+2] + vect[j];
    suff[0] = suff[1];
    
    ll ans = pref[n]; // pref[n+1], suff[0], suff[1]
    
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<=n; j++) {
            if(j-i == 1) 
                ans = max(ans, pref[i]*(-1) + suff[j]*(-1));
            else
                ans = max(ans, pref[i]*(-1) + suff[j]*(-1) + pref[j-1] - pref[i+1-1]);
        }
    }
    
    return ans;
}
```

How can I improve on the Time Complexity ?

Comment: If this is from some coding challenge website, please provide details and include the exact description and constraints of the problem. If you only need the maximum sum, not the is and js, I suspect that is a key fact to improving on your time complexity.

Comment: The details are pretty much the same. The constraints are-
1 <= n <= 10^5
-10^3 <= vect[i] <= 10^3

Answer (score 1):

Let me show the algorithmic solution (`O(n)` time complexity), while skipping its implementation.

First of all, we can state the problem in a different way: we don't let overlapping, e.g.

```
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g
    |           |

          |           |
```

which equals to

```
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g
    |  |

                   |  |
```

but we allow **empty** prefixes and suffixes instead:

```
    # f .. g suffix, empty prefix
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g
    |           |
    |                 |

    # a .. b prefix, empty suffix
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g
    |                 |
          |           |

    # empty prefix and suffix
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g
    |                 |
    |                 |
```

So we can solve the problem in linear time: find the best prefix by using rolling sums (best prefix must have **negative minimum sum**):

```
items:
    1, 2, 3, -9, -8, 3, 4, -1
sums:
    1  3  6  -3 -11 -8 -4  -5
                  ^
                  best prefix (the sum is minimal and negative)
```

similar we can compute the suffix (we compute sums staring from the end in this case):

```
items:
    1, 2, 3, -9, -8, 3, 4, -1
sums:
   -5 -6 -8 -11  -2  6  3  -1
              ^
              best suffix
```

If best prefix and best suffix *don't overlap*, return them as an answer. If prefix and suffix overlap, we should choose between two options:

1. Take the *best prefix* and *the best suffix which doesn't overlap* the taken prefix
2. Take the *best suffix* and *the best prefix which doesn't overlap* the taken suffix

In the example above:

1. Choosing `1, 2, 3, -9, -8` prefix and `-1` suffix, we have **19**
2. Choosing empty prefix and `-9 -8 3 4 -1` suffix, we have **17**

So far so good, we choose 1st option (`19`) which is

```
   1, 2, 3, -9, -8, 3, 4, -1
   |             |        ||
```

Comment: What if there are multiple best prefixes/suffixes. How should we then decide which prefix/suffix we should choose?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using dp.

Let-

- `dpp[i][0]` - value obtained by flipping all elements from `0` to `i`.
- `dpp[i][1]` - maximum value obtained until index i by not flipping `i`.

`dpp[i][0] = dpp[i-1][0] + (-1)*arr[i]` 
`dpp[i][1] = max(dpp[i-1][0], dpp[i-1][1]) + arr[i]`

We can compute for indexes from `1` to `n-2`. 
`sum = max(dp[i][0], dp[i][1]) + (-1)*suff[i+1]`

We can similarly create a `dp` for suffix and the check for a maximum answer.

```
int getMaxInvSum(vector<int>& arr) {
    int n = arr.size();   
    vector<int> pref(n), suff(n);
 
    pref[0] = arr[0];
    for(int i=1; i<n; i++) pref[i] = arr[i] + pref[i-1];
    suff[n-1] = arr[n-1];
    for(int i=n-2; i>=0; i--) suff[i] = arr[i] + suff[i+1];
 
    int ans = pref[n-1] & suff[0];
 
    vector<vector<int>> dpp(n, vector<int>(2));
    dpp[0][0] = (-1)*arr[0];
    dpp[0][1] = (-1)*arr[0];
    for(int i=1; i<n-1; i++) {
        dpp[i][0] = (-1)*arr[i] + dpp[i-1][0];
        dpp[i][1] = arr[i] + max(dpp[i-1][0], dpp[i-1][1]);
    }
 
    for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        ans = max(ans, max(dpp[i][0], dpp[i][1]) + (-1)*suff[i+1]);
 
    vector<vector<int>> dps(n, vector<int>(2));
    dps[n-1][0] = (-1)*arr[n-1];
    dps[n-1][1] = (-1)*arr[n-1];
    for(int i=n-2; i>0; i--) {
        dps[i][0] = (-1)*arr[i] + dps[i+1][0];
        dps[i][1] = arr[i] + max(dps[i+1][0], dps[i+1][1]);
    }
 
    for(int i=n-1; i>0; i--)
        ans = max(ans, max(dps[i][0], dps[i][1]) + (-1)*pref[i-1]);
 
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Consider [166, 468, -449, -599, 823, 719] with i=5, j=4 gives 1956. I think your functions give 1128.

Comment: You are correct!

Comment: My code doesn't include the condition where either the first or last element remain unaffected. This will happen when i = n-1 (for last element) and j = 0 (for first element). We would just use the sum of prefixes and suffixes (like `pref[i] + (-1)*suff[i+1])`